# Pandas Use Index to Replace Row Values with Zero

Tags: pandas, indexing, rows

I need to apply an index from one dataframe "df" (not shown) with a condition True/False of whether the row value in df contains NaN. I have found that index and it is called "rowswithnan" and is shown below is a series. I need to use this index to set the row values of a different dataframe "df2" to zero (0). I have tried lots of things and am getting different errors.

the series rowswithnan index  looks like this:

```
0   False
1   True
2   True
3   False
```

and df2 looks like this:

```
   plant_name  power_kwh  hour  day  month  year
0  AREC        32963.4    23   31     12    2020
1  AREC        35328.2    22   31     12    2020
2  AREC        37523.6    21   31     12    2020
3  AREC        36446.0    20   31     12    2020
```

After using the index of "rowswithnan", I need df2 to look like this with the "zero" replacements in the column "power_kwh":

df2

```
   plant_name  power_kwh  hour  day  month  year
0  AREC        32963.4    23   31     12    2020
1  AREC        0          22   31     12    2020
2  AREC        0          21   31     12    2020
3  AREC        36446.0    20   31     12    2020
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df2.loc[rowswithnan, 'power_kwh'] = 0`

Comment: Hi - thank you but i get this error using your solution that i don't understand - ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: it should work for your sample data. Try with `rowswithnan.values()` instead?

Comment: using . values() gives me this - TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: use `rowswithnan.values`

Comment: My bad for not testing the code. Remove `()`, just `.values`.

Comment: bingo - yes - thank you for both of you

Comment: sorry one more question, what if i wanted to drop the rows instead of setting them = 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a series that describes where NaN are in the dataframe, I'm guessing there's a simpler way to handle this whole situation. However, here's answer to your request in a comment to drop the rows where the index of the series `rowswithnan` is False.

First make that series a column of your dataframe:

```
df['contains_nan'] = `rowswithnan`
```

Then use boolean filtering:

```
df = df.loc[~df.contains_nan]
```

To set the values `power_kwh` to zero instead of dropping the rows, do this:

```
df.loc[df.contains_nan, 'power_kwh'] = 0
```